# How to pipe an email into Django?

Tags: django, pipe, email

I'm part of a two-man business selling LED glow toys and one aspect of this is handling support requests. I have a server running exim4 and DJango and have email working so that if a user sends an email to support@myhost.com I'm able to pick up the email and respond.

I'd like to develop something a bit tidier to keep track of the email chain for a particular support request.

To do this, I was thinking of piping the output of my email using a rule in my support email's filter:

```
pipe /usr/bin/email_to_django_script
```

What I'm unsure of is how best to go about the last step to actually turning the email content into something DJango can process.

What's the best method to do this? Would a script using [curl -d](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) be a sensible option or are there better / less convoluted ways?

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe the output of the email server into a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/).  As an example, I have a file `/inquiries/management/commands/proc_email.py`.  I have a single `Command` class, and the `handle()` method gets most of the email from the environment, and the body of the email from `STDIN`:

```
from_email = strip_tags(os.environ.get('SENDER', None))
to_email = strip_tags(os.environ.get('RECIPIENT', None))
emailMessage = email.message_from_string(''.join(sys.stdin.readlines()))
```

There is other code in there, but that is how I get the important bits out of it.  You can then pipe this into your ORM objects, and access it from the website at some later time.

This is then accessed through `/path/to/project/manage.py proc_email`.

Depending on your email server, you can also use plus addressing to insure replies come back to the same address.  For example, I have my `Reply-To` headers set to `inquiry+12345@whatever.com`.  The mail server (postfix) then dumps this into the environment under `EXTENSION`.  If no number is supplied, I simply create a new Inquiry, instead of attaching to an existing one.

Comment: Looks like I could use the pipe command in exim to pass to a manage.py command: http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/filter_ch03.html

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a pure Django solution but I would recommend taking a look at [Lamson Project](http://lamsonproject.org/). It's an email server written in Python that you can use to build email applications like what you are describing. I can also integrate with the Django ORM. http://lamsonproject.org/docs/hooking_into_django.html